# PHP subtracting strlen($string)

Tags: php, strlen

I would like to invert the value of strlen, how would i do this?

i.e.

```
$string = "123";

echo strlen($string);

3
```

i get the expected result when i do:

```
echo strlen($string)*-1;

-3
```

however, when i do:

```
$var = strlen($string)*-1;

echo $var;
```

i get nada, as in nothing.

Comment: @scrblnrd3, sorry my bad. it's $string, like the others

Comment: Post your entire code please, or at least the method or file

Comment: it's here > http://pastebin.com/iehFFt4n

Comment: Try `var_dump($string)`. Also try putting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of the file

Comment: Everything's working fine on my computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = "123";

echo strlen($string) * -1; // -3
echo 0 - strlen($string);  // -3
```

Comment: — would i need to do anything special if using in a substring? i.e. `substr($string, 0, strlen($string) * -1)`. basically i have `string1.string2` and need to subtract the string2 + 1 from it.

Answer (score 2):

it would just be `echo -strlen("123");` or `echo strlen("123")*-1;`. Both of those return -3

Comment: maybe i'm doing this wrong, but when i do `$var = strlen($string)*-1; echo $var;` i don't get anything back. any ideas?